# pip requirement based on available OS library version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, pygit2

I am developing a python package based on `pygit2`. pygit2 depends on `libgit2`.

Ubuntu 18.04 has version libgit2-2.6

Ubuntu 18.10 has version libgit2-2.7

In my requirements.txt/Pipfile, if I have `"pygit2" = "==0.26.4"`, it works in 18.04 (after doing `apt-get install libgit2-dev`) but not in 18.10. Similarly, depending on `"*"` or `"==0.27"` works on 18.10 but not on 18.04. I have not tried on other distros. Is there a way I can specify like,

```
if os has libgit2-2.6
    pygit2 == 0.26.4
else if os has libgit2-2.7
    pygit2 == 0.27.x
```

I tried `pygit2>=0.26.4`, didn't work for 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify version specific modules by using `platform` module.

```
>>> platform.platform().split('-')[6]
'18.04'
>>>

>>> import platform
>>> if "18.04" in platform.platform():
...   print("install 18.04 modules")
... elif "18.10" in platform.platform():
...   print("Install 18.10 modules")
...
install 18.04 modules
>>>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question is how to put that conditions in `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`?

Comment: Thanks! Even if there was a way to add using `platform`, this makes it specific to Ubuntu, I want it to be based on `libgit2` version. This doesn't scale for the thousands of distros.