# pip - specify download version based on available library version

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I'm developing a Python package `my_package` that depends upon some other package `foo_package`.

There's a few versions of `foo_package` that are used in the community, and unfortunately they're not backwards compatible with each other. (Because of changes to the C interface that my code is compiled against).

So I'd like to distribute multiple copies of `my_package`, corresponding to the different versions of `foo_package`.

I can distinguish these different copies of `my_package` from each other using post-release tags. For example I can give `my_package` the version `1.1.4-foo_package1.2`, corresponding to version `1.1.4` of `my_package` compiled against version `1.2` of `foo_package`.

So far so good. The caveat now is that when it comes to installing this with `pip`, end users have to specify this full version string to be able to get the correct version of `my_package`. That is, they have to know that the latest release of `my_package` is `1.1.4` and that the release of `foo_package` that they're using is `1.2` and thus use the command `pip install my_package==1.1.4-foo_package1.2`.

Obviously this isn't ideal for all sorts of reasons. (End user friendliness, avoiding dependency hell... ) After all, all of this can be determined programmatically!

Is there any sensible way to handle this issue, so that an end user can just run `pip install my_package` and have the correct copy downloaded automatically?

There is one unsatisfactory answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192273/pip-requirement-based-on-available-os-library-version).

FWIW the best solution I've come up with so far is to create another package `my_package_installer` which as part of its `setup.py` checks what version of `foo_package` is installed and then specifies the relevant version of `my_package` as the `install_requires` argument to `setuptools.setup`. But that's completely asinine and seems quite fragile. I can't be the only one with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From a design point of view, it seems to me that you should be specifying one version of foo as a dependency, because that's what works best with your package. If other people have different versions of foo, that's their responsibility.

If it's not so simple and you have a constraint for compatibility with multiple versions of foo, then what I think most developers do is try to detect foo at initialization and adapt to it from there.

Comment: `my_package` is really just a plugin for `foo_package`. I don't want to constrain people to use just the version I happen to have compiled against. (And the fact that it's a compilation-time problem means there's no adaption that can be done during initialisation - unless the end user has a compiler available then it's too late.)

Answer (score 0):

What about creating multiple Python projects from the same code base?

Let's say you have a source code repository `MyProject.git`, and you want to distribute it for `libfoo1.2` and `libfoo1.4`. Then maybe a `setup.py` that looks like this would do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distutils.core
import setuptools

def get_foo_version():
    return '1.2' if True else '1.4'

foo_version = get_foo_version()

foo_module = distutils.core.Extension(
    'foo',
    define_macros=[('FOO_VERSION', foo_version)],
    libraries=['foo{}'.format(foo_version)],
    sources=['foo.c'],
    # ...
)

setuptools.setup(
   name='MyProjectForFoo{}'.format(foo_version),
   ext_modules = [foo_module],
   # ...
)
```

In this scenario you would end up with two Python projects `MyProjectForFoo1.2` and `MyProjectForFoo1.4`. The users of your project would still have to pick the right project, but it would be less prone to confusion than sorting by version numbers.

You could probably use [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/) and/or a good CI/CD system to help you automate the creation and publication of the distributions (*wheels*) for the two (or more) projects.